# Orchard 1.8.1 Installation with MySQL

Tags: mysql, orchardcms

I have been using Orchard 1.8 for my previous project.
I decided to try 1.8.1 I am using MySQL.
Atfer I compiled the sources of Orchard 1.8.1 and installed it with a blank database. The following message occurs in the dashboard:

```
Some features need to be upgraded: Orchard.Autoroute, Orchard.MediaLibrary
```

When I click update. This message occurs:

```
    An unhandled exception has occurred and the request was terminated. Please refresh the page. If the error persists, go back
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'bulkAction' of non-nullable type 'Orchard.Modules.ViewModels.FeaturesBulkAction' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult FeaturesPOST(Orchard.Modules.ViewModels.FeaturesBulkAction, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String], System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean])' in 'Orchard.Modules.Controllers.AdminController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parametername: parameters
```

...

With 1.8 I have noticed some issues too with MySQL. It seems that there are problems with the nullable type.

If there was a way to change the server configuration somehow. I have full acccess to the database server.

Comment: You should probably file a bug.

Comment: https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20807

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is becuased the DisplayAlias index length is set to 2048 bytes, MySQL indexes can be no longer than 767 bytes.

To fix the issue change:

```
SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("AutoroutePartRecord", table => table
                .CreateIndex("IDX_AutoroutePartRecord_DisplayAlias", "DisplayAlias"));
```

to:

```
SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("AutoroutePartRecord", table => table
                .CreateIndex("IDX_AutoroutePartRecord_DisplayAlias", "DisplayAlias(767)"));
```

in Orchard.Autoroutes Migrations.cs

The fix can also be applied to the MediaLibrary Migrations on the "FolderPath" index:

```
SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("MediaPartRecord", t => t
                .CreateIndex("IDX_MediaPartRecord_FolderPath", "FolderPath(767)"));
```

For more detail see [AoutroutePartRecord Index under MySQL Issue](https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20951)

Comment: Thank you. I switched to Orchard with MS SQL Express. Are you using Orchard CMS with MySQL? Do you know if they are going to fix the bug in 1.8.3?

Comment: I am running Orchard with MySQL, however I made the above code change before cooking. If you make the change after orchard has generated the database you will still see the error, I believe you would need to manually change the database.

Comment: Worthwhile to note that `SchemaBuilder.AlterTable(...)` appears more than once in each of the migrations files with the same paramaters! Updating all occurrences seems to have done the trick for me.